# Jquery submit data to second tab in ajax modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cakephp

Is it possible to post data from tab 1 in another second tab in an open ajax modal without reloading the page? If yes, maybe some one of you can give me a hint to do that?

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
        aria-hidden="true"></button>
       <h4 class="modal-title"><?php echo __('Send email'); ?></h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
               <li class="active"> <a href="#tab_1" data-toggle="tab"> <?php echo    __('E-Mail'); ?> </a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="tab-content" style="height: 500px">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab_1">
                <?php echo $this->Form->create('outbox', array('id' => 'mailform')); ?>
                <?php
                $templateArray = [];
                $subjectArray = [];
                $contentArray = [];
                foreach ($templates as $template) {
                    $templateArray[$template->id] = $template->name;
                    $subjectArray[$template->id] = $template->subject;
                    $contentArray[$template->id] = $template->content;
                }
                echo $this->Form->select('template.id', $templateArray, ['label' => __('template'), 'id' =>'template']);
                echo $this->Form->input("recipient", ['label' => __('Recipient'), 'type' => 'email']);
                echo $this->Form->input("subject", ['label' => __('subject'), 'id' => 'subject']);
                echo $this->Form->input('content', ['label' => __('content'), 'type' => 'textarea', 'id' => 'content']);
                ?>
                <a href="#tab_2" data-toggle="tab" data-action="ajax-submit"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"> <?php echo __('preview'); ?> </button> </a>
                <?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_2">
                <?php echo $this->Form->create('outbox', array('id' => 'mailform')); ?>
                <!--<iframe src=""  width="150%" height="500"> </iframe>-->
                <?php
                echo $this->Form->input('preview_body', ['label' => __('preview'), 'type' => 'textarea', 'id' => 'body']);
                ?>
                <a href="#tab_1" data-toggle="tab"> <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"> <?php echo __("edit"); ?> </button></a>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-action="ajax-submit" data-url="/ajax_info_mail" data-form-id="mailform"> <?php echo __("send"); ?> </button>
                <?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default"> <?php echo __("abort"); ?> </button
</div>
```

So the sender selects one template of the array and by clicking on preview it should be load the preview with the replaced subject and content into the template in the second tab. If the user want's to edit the email, he get's back to the first tab.

Comment: If it's from one tab to another, I would use localstorage or a cookie. Unless the data need to be persisted at the server; in that case use ajax.

Comment: Could you provide some code? are the tabs in the same randered html?

Comment: Post? Everything is all on the same page; just read from source and update the destination tab before closing the modal.

Comment: Ok. But how can i do that, without reloading the ajax modal?